# Fedora vs Ubuntu ... Massive difference in performance

Tags: r, performance, ubuntu, performance-testing, fedora

I have recently bought a new ZBook fury G10 for data science.

I have tried the R script below to test performance in a fedora 38 installation and an Ubuntu 22.04 installation -- both entirely fresh installations.

This is the thing ... the difference in run time for the R script is almost a factor 40 !!

In Fedora, it takes 1.2 seconds to complete -- in Ubuntu, it take 44 seconds!

I don't know where to start looking to understand this. Any suggestions?

```
# Set matrix dimensions
matrix_size <- 4000

# Generate random matrices
set.seed(123)
matrix_a <- matrix(rnorm(matrix_size^2), nrow = matrix_size, ncol =
                     matrix_size)
matrix_b <- matrix(rnorm(matrix_size^2), nrow = matrix_size, ncol =
                     matrix_size)

# Measure time taken on
start_time_p52s <- Sys.time()
result_p52s <- matrix_a %*% matrix_b
end_time_p52s <- Sys.time()

# Calculate time taken on
time_taken_p52s <- end_time_p52s - start_time_p52s

# Print time taken on
cat("Time taken to complete: ", time_taken_p52s, " seconds\n")
```

session info:

Fedora:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: FlexiBLAS OPENBLAS-OPENMP;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: US/Eastern
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1
```

Ubuntu:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_DK.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_DK.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_DK.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1
```

Linux Mint:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 21.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2
```

Comment: My guess is that it is related to whichever libraries you're linking to, not sure if LAPACK or BLAS are the culprits here. I don't have a resolution for this, but look at the linked libraries to see potential differences.

Comment: Print out the `sessionInfo()` on both machines.

Comment: Inserted above ...

Comment: I've tried with the latest Linux Mint as well -- as slow as Ubuntu.
I'll try a Debian 12 shortly.

Comment: Install the (optional, not default) OpenBLAS on Ubuntu too and it will (near-)identical.  You are comparing multi-core to single-core.  You could also pick the MKL for another little speed gain (at the expense of more disk space covered),

Comment: OpenBLAS fixed the issue -- now less than 1 second on Ubuntu -- same as Fedora. 

This is interesting. Wonder why OpenBLAS isn't the default.

Comment: The 40x speedup is mostly due to memory hierarchy optimization in OpenBLAS vs default NETLIB. While muti-core is involved too, it likely gives only additional 4x or less. Fedora also adds a FlexiBLAS layer that can be used with the flexiblas R package to further optimize core use in specific operations.